# Counting number of sequential occurences for a person - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sas, cumulative-sum

I have a table like:

```
Name | ID | Event
Smith| 1  | 
Smith| 2  | Y
Smith| 3  | 
Jones| 1  | 
Jones| 2  | Y
Jones| 3  | 
Jones| 4  | Y
```

I'd like to count the number of times an Event has been seen for each person at each point, e.g.:

```
Name | ID | Event | Event Count
Smith| 1  |       | 0
Smith| 2  | Y     | 1
Smith| 3  |       | 1
Jones| 1  |       | 0
Jones| 2  | Y     | 1
Jones| 3  |       | 1
Jones| 4  | Y     | 2
```

I'm guessing I can't do this in SQL?  If not, can you be very clear how I go about doing this in SAS (or whatever way is appropriate), as I am new to this!

(FYI, this is leading to me being able to differentiate rows that happen before or after each event - i.e. filter by Event = blank, and anything 0 happened before the first event, anything 1 after, etc.  There might be an easier way to do this.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to go down the SAS route, it reads data sequentially so is very good at this type of problem

```
data have;
infile datalines missover;
input Name $ ID  Event $;
datalines;
Smith 1   
Smith 2   Y
Smith 3   
Jones 1   
Jones 2   Y
Jones 3   
Jones 4   Y
;
run;

proc sort data=have;
by name id;
run;

data want;
set have;
by name id;
if first.name then event_count=0;
event_count+(event='Y');
run;
```

Comment: Definitely the way to go if you're using SAS.  Should be much faster than the SQL since it only goes through the data once if it's already sorted.

Comment: Awesome - thank you so much.  Quick question - why is it necessary to sort the data (second block of code) if it's already soted?  SAS won't run it without me including that code, but the input data was already sorted.  And why is 'by name id;' required in the third bit of code?

Comment: Well, the data sample isn't sorted alphabetically so I put in that step.  There is a way to avoid the sort if you're sure that the names are grouped together and the id's are sorted correctly.  In that case add the NOTSORTED option to the BY statement in the data step, this will reset the counter every time the name changes.  The BY statement is required because that gives access to the FIRST.var automatic variables. Technically you only need the NAME variable in there, I added ID as a double check that the data is sorted correctly. So the line can say :
by name notsorted;

Answer (score 3):

You could potentially do something like this in a query:

```
select Name, ID, Event,
    (
        select count(*)
        from MyTable
        where Name = t.Name
            and Event = 'Y'
            and ID <= t.ID
    ) as EventCount
from MyTable t
```

The correlated subquery will find this count for you, though this is something of a [triangular join](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/) (SQL Server link, but still applicable), so performance isn't wonderful.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c960ad/1) showing the result.

Note that this should work in virtually any RDBMS.

Comment: That's great - thanks. I'm not 100% sure how it works, but I'll play with it until I understand!  And the SQL Fiddle thing is great!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Name, ID, Event, grpTotal
FROM
  (
    select  Name,
            ID,
            Event,
            @sum := if(@grp = Name,@sum,0) + if(`Event` = 'Y',1,0) as grpTotal,
            @grp := Name
    from    TableName,
            (select @grp := '', @sum := 0) vars
    order   by  Name, ID
  ) s
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61ccf/13)

Comment: Thanks.  In terms of performance, which is going to be better, yours or Tim's?

Comment: @user2174526 You should test both queries on your real data and see which is faster.